# How to create a zip file in memory with a list of PIL image objects?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, zip, in-memory

I am trying to create a zip file in memory with a list of PIL image objects.

```
import io
from PIL import Image

def get_images(path):
    '''This returns a list of PIL images'''
    pass


def file_process_im_memory():
    images = get_images('mypath')
    file_object = io.BytesIO()
    file_object2 = io.BytesIO()
    images[0].save(file_object, 'PNG')
    images[1].save(file_object2, 'PNG')
    file_object.seek(0)
    file_object2.seek(0)
```

The image are written in memory, now I want to create an zip file from the in memory image files, I tried below but it didn't work.

```
zip_file = ZipFile(zip_file_bytes_io, 'w')
for image in images:
    file_object = io.BytesIO()
    image.save(file_object, 'PNG')
    file_object.seek(0)
    zip_file.writestr(file_object.getvlaue())
zip_file_bytes_io.seek(0)
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe this will do what you want. As I said in a now deleted comment, one issue was that the first argument to `zip_file.writestr()` should be the filename / member name it will be given in the archive with the second one being the data to be written.

In order to be able to do that the image filenames must be preserved. In the code below `get_images()` now returns a list of `[<image file name>, <PIL image object>]` **pairs** of values so the name will be available when writing the in-memory zip file.

```
import io
import os
from PIL import Image
from pprint import pprint
from zipfile import ZipFile


def get_images(path):
    """ Returns a list of image file base name & PIL image object pairs. """

    # Harcoded with two images for testing purposes.
    IMAGES = (r"C:\vols\Files\PythonLib\Stack Overflow\cookie_cutter_background.png",
              r"C:\vols\Files\PythonLib\Stack Overflow\Flying-Eagle.png")

    images = []
    for image_path in IMAGES:
        # Get image file name without extension.
        image_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.os.path.basename(image_path))[0]
        pil_image = Image.open(image_path)
        images.append([image_name, pil_image])

    return images


def file_process_in_memory():
    """ Converts PIL image objects into BytesIO in-memory bytes buffers. """

    images = get_images('mypath')

    for i, (image_name, pil_image) in enumerate(images):
        file_object = io.BytesIO()
        pil_image.save(file_object, "PNG")
        pil_image.close()
        images[i][1] = file_object  # Replace PIL image object with BytesIO memory buffer.

    return images  # Return modified list.


images = file_process_in_memory()

# Create an in-memory zip file from the in-memory image file data.
zip_file_bytes_io = io.BytesIO()

with ZipFile(zip_file_bytes_io, 'w') as zip_file:
    for image_name, bytes_stream in images:
        zip_file.writestr(image_name+".png", bytes_stream.getvalue())

    pprint(zip_file.infolist())  # Print final contents of in memory zip file.

print('done')
```

Sample output:

```
[<ZipInfo filename='cookie_cutter_background.png' filemode='?rw-------' file_size=727857>,
 <ZipInfo filename='Flying-Eagle.png' filemode='?rw-------' file_size=462286>]
done
```

Comment: I tried validating the above code by writing the created zip file into disk seems like the file gets corrupted, maybe I am doing something wrong.
```with open('tmp.zip', 'wb') as f:
     f.write(zip_file_bytes_io.read())
```

Comment: That's because you're doing it wrong — use `f.write(zip_file_bytes_io.getvalue())`.

Comment: using f.write(zip_file_bytes_io.getvalue()) does not writes the zip file correctly and the zip file gets corrupted

Comment: It worked for me when I tested it (before making my comment suggesting the use of `getvalue()`) — so there must be something else wrong. How are you determining that the file created is corrupt?

Comment: by unzip the file or opening the file by directly

Comment: That's what I did, too. Not only did it work without error, I was also able to view the extracted images afterwards (and they were correct).

Comment: its important to first close the zip_file before saving it